# Php, sql проблема с кодировкой

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Вопрос закрыт. Всё решилось одной строкой:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Дело в том, что на странице никаких "крякозябров", а вот в таблице sql творится беспредел. Не просто знаки вопроса или тому подобное, а самые настоящие крякозябры. Но это относится только к русским буквам.

На sql установлена utf8_general_ci.

Конечно пробовала ещё какими-то образами изменить кодировку на utf-8, но безуспешно. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: при подключении к БД вы в сессии кодировку выставляете ,

Comment: Вы через что смотрите в sql с кракозябрами?

Comment: Какая кодировка установлена для страницы - meta charset?

Comment: Вы не видите, что "творится" в таблице. В принципе - если, конечно, не просматриваете файлы таблиц, минуя сервер, прямо в файловой системе. Вы видите данные, которые прошли минимум две обработки - между сервером и драйвером доступа, и между драйвером и программой-клиентом. Ну и в принципе клиент ещё при выводе на экран мог подшаманить... И угадать, в настройке какого из этих этапов, и тем более в какой именно настройке, косяк, с таким минимумом фактов нереально.

Comment: @Mike,  в сессии вставлять? Это как?

Comment: @Visman, если я правильно поняла, то через mySQL. Только не кидайте тапками, если ответила совсем не то ><

Comment: $SergeyMoiseenko, да,     <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: @Біпач Под сессией я имел ввиду подключение к БД. Вижу под комментом под ответом, что вы это уже делаете. Остался вопрос, а вы так же делали, когда создавали записи в БД ? потому что после изменения такой настройки все записи в БД созданные при других настройках будут нечитабельны ...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать набор символов, который используется при обращении с базой данных. Это делается с помощью [mysqli::set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Чтобы знать что конкретно вам нужно написать - необходимо знать как вы подключаетесь к БД, т.к. есть устаревшие функции mysql_*, теперь вместо них можно использовать mysqli как в процедурном стиле, так и в объектном.

Comment: изначальная кодировка - latin1.  Это я узнала с помощью '$connection->character_set_name()'. Потом попыталась поменять на utf8:                                                                                     `if (!$connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", $connection->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Текущий набор символов: %s\n", $connection->character_set_name());
}`, но в результате этого крякозябры отобразились и на странице

Comment: Кодировка latin в принципе не поддерживает кириллицу. У вас всё должно быть в одной кодировке - база, страница. И тогда задание набора символов поможет. А может и вообще не нужно будет.

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте в самый верх страницы `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`   :)

Comment: уже решила, но спасибо) А так, кстати, может вы знаете каким образом можно предотвратить sql инъекции?

Comment: Смотря что вы делаете, есть ли у вас поиск по бд, добавление записей или запросы какие может